# System Failing to Boot 12.04 udev timeout killing '/sbin message

Tags: boot

I have a HP Pavilion DV6000 with Ubuntu 12.04 installed from a USB drive.

I tried to do a few things I read on a couple big Linux/Ubuntu blogs - like change the swappiness, switch to the 2D desktop interface to try and speed this older laptop up.

Afterwards I had to reboot. Upon reboot I was prompted with a GNU Grub menu where I could select Ubuntu with or without recovery mode along with memory test.

Memory and disk tests turned up no errors.

When I try to load Ubuntu, either with or without the recovery mode I get a few

```
udevd[number]:timeout: killing: '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p
```

messages repeating.

I can enter the grub command line - can I do anything from there? If not, what else can I do to recover this PC and not lose what's on it?

If I have to reinstall I will, but I'd rather not.